# What are the advantages and disadvantages of incremental learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, boosting

Generally speaking, it's to save spaces with incremental learning.

According to the [question in stackoverflow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51260/what-are-the-advantages-of-online-learning-when-training-neural-networks) , it also said that.

But what are the disadvantages?

What I know from my experiments are two points:

1. Train with subsets of data **but shouldn't be too small**. I prepared very small datasets and the predict result is much worse.
2. When training for a very long time, some older behaviors will be forgotten due to the multiple training epochs.

That's all from my experience when training with **xgboost** incrementally.

Or anything else?

Comment: An epoch general refers to as one full pass through the training data. So the training set is repeated each epoch. Each epoch consists of many batches, usually.

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated. Instead of just having all the entire dataset in memory and doing performing a single fit, there are now more things to do:

- Need a way to load data in batches from disk
- Need to decide a new hyperparameter, the batchsize